# Is Jack and Rose's love story real?

Tags: realism, titanic

In the film *Titanic*, did the story of Jack and Rose actually happen in real life?

Comment: I think it's real.

Comment: Please take the time to read the [Help pages](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Several aspects of the movie are real like the preist refusing to leave or the band playing on until the end. The main story on the other hand is 100% fiction.

Comment: I disagree with the Opinion Based reason, the question has an answer from a respected authority in history; history.com.  https://www.history.com/news/the-true-stories-that-inspired-titanic-movie-characters#:~:text=You%20probably%20already%20knew%20that,fictional%20elements%20to%20historical%20events.

Comment: I've re-worded the question to turn it from a subjective "do you think it's real" to an objective "is it actually real", and I'm voting to re-open.

Comment: @F1Krazy - agreed. As a simple 'is this a true story?" with the realism tag, it's answerable. As a prompt to a free-for-all discussion "What do you think? I think it is" it wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

> Is Jack and Rose's love story real?

Then the answer will be, No.

But there are other secondary characters who are based on real-life people. [History.com](https://www.history.com/news/the-true-stories-that-inspired-titanic-movie-characters) tried to list them.

But many people draw a parallel between Jack and Rose to Romeo and Juliet, forbidden love, rich-poor, and R+J. And also from [eyeforfilm](https://www.eyeforfilm.co.uk/feature/2009-12-17-james-cameron-talks-about-avatar-aliens-and-his-titanic-career-feature-story-by-maria-realf):

> Having made a name for himself as a skilled sci-fi and action director, James’s decision to make a period love story – which he pitched to Fox as **“Romeo and Juliet on the Titanic”**

Answer (score 2):

No, the love story [wasn't real.](https://www.history.com/news/the-true-stories-that-inspired-titanic-movie-characters#:%7E:text=You%20probably%20already%20knew%20that,fictional%20elements%20to%20historical%20events.)  Some of the events were based on true events (i.e. The Unsinkable Molly Brown demanding the lifeboat go back to look for survivors), but Jack and Rose were pure fiction.

Interestingly, there was a Joseph Dawson aboard the Titanic, and his gravestone (simply marked "J Dawson") [has been the focal point of some fans of the movie](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/titanic-film-fans-flock-to-halifax-for-j-dawson-grave-1.1191689).